# Start android application before system application

Tags: android, performance

I have made and an Android application that asks for password before installing and uninstalling any other Application.

It works fine, but the problem is in on start-up: when I restart the phone it takes time to start my application. At this time every user can install or uninstall any application without password. Can I start my android application before system applications???
Or any other solution of this problem?

Comment: on reboot just lock the screen!

Comment: why should i lock screen?

Comment: How do you start your application automatically after each re-boot? Do you start it `on boot completed` or in some other way?

Comment: yes i have a broadCast reciver i start it on boot completed